LiveData in shared ViewModel crashing while setting empty observer - "Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles"
I have a ViewModel scoped to activity. It has a MediatorLiveData to observe data from multiple sources. To make the this mediator live data work I have added an empty observer in the fragment like this
viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {}

When I open the same instance of the fragment again it's crashing at the exact same line saying Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles.
Upon diving deep I identified that the observer created from second instance of the fragment returns true when .equals() with the observer created from first instance of the fragment. This makes the LiveData think that the observer is already attached with a different lifecycle owner even tho the instance of the observer is different and has different memory reference value.
In the attached image of LiveData#observe method, when the second fragment is trying to call observe(), in line 197 ideally the existing should have been null as this is a new instance of Observer but still the observer from first instance of the fragment was returned there.

I have solved this by changing {} to viewModel.liveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {}) while observing the LiveData but I wanted to know what caused this issue. Also, is there any better way to handle MediatorLiveData in this case? 
